# can i run Firefox from terminal and further use this terminal for other work in WSL ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

can i run Firefox from terminal and further use this terminal for other work in WSL ubuntu ?

Comment: I don't use WSL, but if I'm using a terminal & want to start a new `firefox` session (*and keep my terminal for my own usage*), i just start it in the background; ie. `firefox &`   Do note:  if the background `firefox` has stdout messages, I'll likely see them on that terminal...